# Cpanel lost a password protected directory

Tags: php, cpanel, administration

I did some work for a client and decided that for a simple site like his, a password protected directory would suffice for keeping his administration files safe.

He uses [CPanel](http://cpanel.net/) to handle his actual website, and so we just used the [CPanel password protection](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/PasswordProtectDirectories).

I just got a call from him saying that the files are [404ing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404), so I went and looked at the directory, and all of the files are gone.

Is it possible that the files were:

- deleted by CPanel
- deleted by the server itself
- deleted by accident

Thanks in advance. Google was no help.

Comment: most likely human error

Comment: I've come to completely trust computers. Files don't just disappear, someone must have deleted them, either using the CPanel interface or using another client such as ftp or ssh.

Comment: it is also possible that some miscellaneous guy may deleted ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cpanel can't delete files or folders until gives command to do so, If your client has lost content there should another reason like files deleted accidentally.